# Ant build to clear dependent class files

Tags: java, ant

My single Java file compiles into 10 class files. For Example, `Example.java` compiles into `example1.class`, `example2.class`, etc. How to write an ant build to clean these multiple class files generated for a single java file?

Comment: clear the folder or do you have other classes there as well?

Comment: I have there other class files too

Comment: Not sure, is <include name="Example*.class" /> tag in your delete folder task doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete>
      <fileset dir="${dist}" includes="Example*/*.class"/>
    </delete>
</target>
```

Comment: @Mureinik ... thanks, yes it should be dist or bin from where you want to clear

Comment: thank you garry. How to check list of last modified files in ant build